# Powershell - Regarding List

Tags: powershell

Can you please provide me a way in powershell to declare collection List from type keyvaluepair, and the way to add elements from this type. Is not acceptable to use Hashtable, it is necessary to use List of this type.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what's stopping you from just going ahead and creating such a list.

```
$list = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[KeyType,ValueType]]'
```